# php order form price updating

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I have a php order form  that worked perfectly until prices started changing too often and it becomes a pain to manage. my order form uses the checkbox value on the html form  and the processorder.php page to insert the `$_POST` value into the database. If checkbox value and processorder.php value not = then nothing inserts into db(see processorder.php sample below)

```
if(isset($_POST['MainMeal']) && $_POST['MainMeal'][2] == '75')
{
$MainM2 = "ToastedHamCheese";
}
```

The question is how does one manage a price list that is changing every week. I will then have to go in and change the html checkbox values and the php code. I guess my php is incorrect. please point me to a method that I can manage items and prices from one place.
I have attempted building a gui page with input boxes and use sql update statements.Ideal situation would be to have an easy to use page so that others can manage price list and don't have to know php. Please help and thanks in advance.

Comment: Periphrase your question, make it simplier, divided to logical stages. It's too difficult to understand.

Comment: I just got hungry. Some CMS will be useful, as nobody wants to edit html manually these days.

Comment: How many items in your database? Tens, hundreds, thousands?

Comment: Lol sorry hungry programmers are no good. I need to look into cms thanks will get back to you if it is the solution.

Comment: Basically I have a manage price page which updates the db but I can't get the order page to have a checkbox item that will use the updated db prices.

Comment: I have about 100 items. but still it takes two hours to update prices and I have to make sure that if I changed on html form that the processorder.php is matching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always a good idea to have the source of information in just one place. I would recommend, if you have people "who don't know php", to have a "manage price" page on a protected part of your website that provide ability for authorized people to update the price in your database.

Then the actual order page is generated with php and pulls the up to date price from the database.

It requires a rewrite of your site - but do it once and it will be much easier to manage going forward.

**UPDATED** I created a more complete example - this allows you to check items from the list, and it will then do some simple processing on those items. You will see how you can apply this to your situation. The key is to give the checkboxes a name ending in `[]` - this makes the `_POST` variable an array with all the checkboxes that are set, and allows you to loop over all the elements. Also note that I made a copy of all the prices when generating the price list - this allows me to quickly add the prices (the index is the value of each checkbox, which makes this a really convenient way to do things). php is nice enough to adjust the size of the array automatically…

Finally - I check which items were checked, so when I re-generate the form, I populate the checkboxes that were previously set.

Obviously there are many ways in which you can embellish this - for example you could add filters to show only "vegetarian" options in the menu, etc…

See this at work at http://www.floris.us/SO/priceList.php

Here is a before/after screen shot:

Before submitting:

[image]

After submitting:

[image]

Code used to generate these:

```
<html>
<body>
  <?php
    $server = mysql_connect ('localhost', 'name', 'password');
    mysql_select_db("db", $server);

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `priceList`;");
    $prices = array();
    echo '<center><h1>Dynamic price list</h1><br>';
    echo '<table><TD></TD><TD>ITEM</TD><TD>PRICE</TD>';
    echo "<form action='./priceList.php' method='post'>";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
        echo '<TR><TD><input type="checkbox" name="order[]" value="' . $row['ID'] . '" ';
        // check the box if we are processing form:
        if (isset($_POST['order'])) {
          if (in_array($row['ID'],$_POST['order'])) echo "checked=checked";
        }
        echo '></TD>';
        echo "<TD>".$row['ITEM'] . '</TD><TD align=right>$ ' . $row['PRICE'] . '</TD>';
        $prices[$row['ID']] = $row['PRICE'];

    }
    echo '</TABLE>';
    mysql_close($server);
  ?>
  <input type="submit"><br>
  <?php
  if(isset($_POST['order'])) {
    // add the value of the items:
    $orderTotal = 0;
    //print_r($_POST['order']);
    foreach($_POST['order'] as $val) {
      $orderTotal = $orderTotal + $prices[$val];
      echo "Price of item " . $val . " is " . $prices[$val] ."<br>";
    }
    setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_US');
    echo 'Order total: ' . money_format('%i', $orderTotal) . '<br>';
  }
    else {
    // do nothing
  }
  ?>
  </center>
</body>
</html>
```

The code has no idea how many items there are, or what they will be called - and yet, it produces a (rather simply formatted) price list with all the items. When you place an order, it shows the price of individual items below the order list, plus their total (just to show how this is done).

As it is, the table I created for this example has just three columns (ID, ITEM, PRICE). Obviously you might want to add further columns to make it do much more - but again, if you think about the database structure up front, you will be able to minimize how much HTML you need, and how much maintenance it requires. And that is the key here:

## the source of information should exists in one place only

and everything else references it from there. As soon as you break that rule, you create a maintenance nightmare. Every time.

Comment: Hi Thanks Floris, I have all the above security features on my "manage price page". but when you say the actual order page is generated with php? please explain because at the moment I use html form.

Comment: You can use a mixture of html and php on a page - where php is used to create dynamic content. There are countless examples online; you could start with http://www.techrepublic.com/article/use-php-for-database-access-and-deliver-dynamic-web-content/ to get an idea. Basically anything you could type in html you could "echo" in php - but in the latter case the contents can change as the database changes, without any change to the php source file.

Comment: Thanks again Floris, I understand the concept and have an idea but want to clarify with you before I head in wrong direction. Is it a good idea to create a variable or functions.php page and define all my items for sale as variables. i.e $ToastedCheese=mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM stock Where item=ToastedCheese); Then no matter what the pricelist manager sets the price I can use $ToastedCheese.Price as my html checkbox value?(I can do this in cold fusion, I would use $sqlvarname.columnheading to get price. will have to check how it is done in php) Is this a good idea or is there an easier way?

Comment: Even easier is to have an array of all the items and their prices - and loop through this array to create all the HTML elements. That way, if you add or remove items from the price list you still don't need to change the php/HTML file. Make sense?

Comment: Thanks Floris for pointing me in the right direction. I see the user below named Uours has mentioned the use of the array idea. I will fiddle around and see how it goes.

Comment: Hi Floris, this is really awesome I am almost there, except when I try to capture the selected order into my db table I am not sure how to use the values of the variable driven checkbox. Usually I would use $_POST['nameofcheckbox'] but in this case the name is a variable.

Comment: I have updated the example - the checkbox variable is now an array, and you will see how to access "all the checked boxes". Some other embellishments added too. Enjoy!

Comment: Happy new year in deed, Thanks Floris have a prosperous 2014. I can say that I will thanks to your help, may god bless your soul. This is working beautifully.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
/*
 * This is just to give an idea ! 
 * You could put data in a separate file or in a database table as individual
 * rows . Just for example sake I've included it here directly .
 */
    $data ='
75:ToastedHamCheese,
76:ToastedCheese,
';
    // Parse data and put into an array
    foreach( explode( ',' ,$data ) as $value )
    {
        $value = trim( $value );
        if( $value <> '' )
        {
            $temp = explode( ':' ,$value );
            $dataValuesArray[ $temp[0] ] = $temp[1];
        }
    }

//  var_dump( $dataValuesArray );

    $_POST['MainMeal'][2] = 75; // For test purpose

    if( isset( $_POST['MainMeal'] )
        and
        array_key_exists( $_POST['MainMeal'][2] ,$dataValuesArray )
    )
    {
        $MainM2 = $dataValuesArray[ $_POST['MainMeal'][2] ];
        echo $MainM2; // For test purpose
    }
?>
```